# SELECT COUNT if statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

Ok, so it seems like my SELECT count query doesn't work here:

```
<?php

    $servername = " "; 
    $username = " "; 
    $password = " "; 
    $dbname = " "; 

    // Create connection 
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); 
    // Check connection 
    if ($conn->connect_error) { 
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error); 
    } 


    if (isset($_POST['submitted1'])) {

        $result= mysqli_query("SELECT COUNT (Motspillerid) 
                              FROM SESSION 
                              WHERE Motspillerid= 3 ");
        echo $result ;
    } else {
        echo "Wrong" ;     
    }

?>
```

And when I press submitt nothing happens, I don't get any error message and I don't get the result. So it's something wrong with the SELECT query I guess.

I'm noob I know, I'm new to this.

:)

Comment: Try to echo the query and perform it through phpMyAdmin to see what happen. **Please also note: mysql_** syntax was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and **it was removed** in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the **[MySQLi](http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** or **[PDO_MySQL](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php)** extension should be used.

Comment: Change `echo $result` to `var_dump($result)`. Then, [stop using mysql and start using PDO or mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14110189#14110189).

Comment: Might want to fetch a row from the result first!

Comment: Ok @cale_b , I did that, and know I'm getting something. The error message "Wrong" xD. So it's still something wrong here

Comment: Please dont use the `mysql_` database extension, it is deprecated (gone for ever in PHP7)
Especially if you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli_` database extensions,
[and here is some help to decide which to use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). Try a tutorial like this one http://www.jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html

Comment: Ok, anyways, if I change the variable criteria to a specific data like : motspillerid = 3 ;      I still get the error message Wrong.

Comment: If you change your question in future please post a comment saying so, that way people who have already given an answer will know that they may need to change their answer accordingly. _Although you are not supposed to change an question once an answer has been provided as it makes existing answers look ridiculous_ You are only supposed to edit the question to add more detail!

Comment: oki, I apologize for that

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling `mysqli_query()` correctly, the first argument has to be the database connection object returned by `mysqli_connect`.

And after performing the query, you have to fetch the results using one of the `mysqli_fetch_X()` functions.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted1'])) {

    $result= mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
                          FROM SESSION 
                          WHERE Motspillerid= 3 ");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row['count'];
} else {
    echo "Wrong" ;     
}
```

Comment: Now I get the error message : Couldn't fetch mysqli in ... and mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Comment: Did you set `$conn` before this? How did you set it?

Comment: $servername = "        ";
$username = "           ";
$password = "            ";
$dbname = "              ";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}                 @Barmar

Comment: Are you running the query in a different function than the one that opens the connection? You need to pass `$conn` as a parameter to the function, or use `global $conn;`.

Comment: Couldn't fetch mysqli in .....Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in ....

Comment: Do you understand PHP variable scoping?

Comment: `couldn't fetch mysqli` means there's something wrong with the `$conn` argument to `mysqli_query`. All you have to do is google for that error message and you'll find other SO questions that explain this.

Comment: Ops, I'm bit sleepy hehe, no I don't know what variable scoping is

Comment: A variable that's assigned outside a function isn't visible inside the function, unless you use the `global` declaration in the function.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and/16959577#16959577